# AVL Tree Union worst case complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, avl-tree

I have an empty AVL Tree and two AVL Trees. I want to get the union of both trees. I do so using an inorder traversal of both trees and inserting (O(log(n)) in the do part of the traversal ie.

```
AVLTree TreeUnion(t1, t2){
    newTree = AVLTreeNew();
    traverse(t1->root, newTree);
    traverse(t2->root, newTree);
    return(newTree);
}
```

```
void traverse(AVLTree t1, AVLTree newTree){
if(t == NULL){
    return;
}
    traverse(t->left);
    AVLInsert(newTree, t->item);
    traverse(t->left);
}
```

I do this on both trees.

I'm confused about the complexity analysis of this because I thought about it and the tree size is constantly increasing so we start off with a tree of size one which is either O(1) or O(log(1)) I'm not too sure because there's no rotation. The tree size is increasing so we get O(1/log(1)) + O(log(2)) + O(log(3)) + O(log(4)) + O(log(5)) + O(log(n-1)) + O (log(n)) + O(n) + O(m)

We get a sum of logarithmic times + the sum of the primitive operations of traversing through the tree in complexity calculation.

if t1->size = x = 3 and t2->size = y = 3. I have calculated this to be. Log(1) + Log(2) + Log(3) + Log(4) + Log(5) + Log(6) + t1->size + t2->size.

Giving an overall worst-case complexity of O(x + y). Is this correct or am I doing it wrong? If so why? I have trouble calculating the complexity of recursive functions.

Any steps toward the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: log(0) is not 1.  It's usually regarded as either undefined or minus infinity.  log(1) is 0.  You seem to have some basic math confusion.  Hint: If log(a) = b, then e^b = a (assuming e is the base of the log).

Comment: I would be tempted to simplify it as O(n log n) where n is x + y.

Comment: Note that inserting into a "self-balancing" tree in ascending or descending order about guarantees maximal balancing effort. Inserting in *level order* would result in no greater unbalance than in the source trees. Alternating between the sources "Bresenham style" looks advantageous.

Comment: (C?) Are you asking about your analysis of the procedure presented, or the tightest upper bound possible among all algorithms?

Comment: The analysis of the procedure presented.

Answer (score 1):

If the total size of the new tree is N, then it will be less than N/2 for the first half of the inserts, and at least N/2 for the last half of the inserts.

Consider *just the last half*:  This takes at least Ω(N/2 * log(N/2)) = Ω(N log N) time.

Your whole algorithm can't be faster than just the last half, so you have an O(N log N) algorithm.